# Apply function doesn't replace values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace nan values of age based on the median of some corresponding groups. I've made a table called grouped_median using groupby. This is my code:

```
def fillAges(row, grouped_median):
    return grouped_median.loc[row['Sex'], row['Class'], row['Title']]['Age'] 


df['Age'] = df.apply(lambda x : fillAges(x, grouped_median) if np.isnan(x['Age']) else x['Age'], axis=1)

df
```

If I print only this part:

```
print(df.apply(lambda x : fillAges(x, grouped_median) if np.isnan(x['Age']) else x['Age'], axis=1))
```

The values are correct but then once I look at the df, the nan values are not replaced. I appreciate any help. Thank you!

EDIT: As Nathaniel said, this code works fine. Indeed df is a big dataframe concatenated from both train and test datasets with one extra flag column that is either "train" or "test". Then this is what I was doing:

```
df[df['flag']=='train']['Age'] = df[df['flag']=='train'].apply(lambda x : fillAges(x, grouped_median) if np.isnan(x['Age']) else x['Age'], axis=1)
```

and it wouldn't work. This would give me this warning but I thought it was only a warning not meaning that it wasn't doing actually anything!!! "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead See the caveats in the documentation: pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/…

All what I needed to do was to remove the [df['flag']=='train'] part from the left.

I'm still not sure why this approach wasn't working. If anyone has an insight, I appreciate to know it. Thank you

Comment: Check out this post about using `fillna()` for imputation (i.e. filling missing data with median): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617811/imputation-of-missing-values-for-categories-in-pandas

Comment: Thank you! But this doesn't work for me. I want to use the median of specific groups. I've made my table and I use the apply function. Median is not my problem actually. My problem is that why the data is not replaced in the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to format for function to take a series and return a series rather than operate on just an element of the series. I've added the function `series_op` below that should do this for you.

```
def fillAges(row, grouped_median):
    return grouped_median.loc[row['Sex'], row['Class'], row['Title']]['Age'] 

def series_op(x):
    x['Age'] = fillAges(x, grouped_median) if np.isnan(x['Age']) else x['Age']
    return x


corrected_df = df.apply(series_op, axis=1)
```

I don't have your data nor `grouped_median` so I can't replicate your problem.  With some test data that I've cooked up, I am able to get this to work correctly, but also able to get yours to work correctly.

Comment: Not true. `apply()` most certainly return values.

Comment: Thank you so much Nathaniel! Works great. Sorry but I don't get why my approach was wrong. My code would take the elements of a series that were required and would return those elements and I would expect to assign them to my df. I'm trying to learn; why was it not working? Should I never pass a portion of a series to #apply function?

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Please accept my answer.  --- I'm not sure why your way didn't work for you.  I would have to see the data you're using to figure it out.  With my toy data, both my method and your method worked just fine.

Comment: Absolutely. I figured what I was doing wrong and added it as an EDIT at the end of my post but still am not sure why it wasn't working. What I was doing gives me this warning but I thought it was only a warning not meaning that it wasn't doing actually anything!!!
"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy"