# Replace missing value with most frequent column item. (Imputer())-Python scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

How do I replace missing value with most frequent column item. (Imputer()) in this dataset "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/voting-records/house-votes-84.data"

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to replace you NaN values.

Try this -- [Imputation of missing values for categories in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617811/imputation-of-missing-values-for-categories-in-pandas)