# Pandas df.mode() of columns not working like df.mean(). Mode of all columns not obtained like mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

seeing my problem tried to replicate it in a simple example to avoid sharing my data.

A sample pd DF:

```
df_sample = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [float('nan'), 8]], columns=["A", "B"])
```

Tried calculating mean for all columns using:

```
df_sample.mean()
```

Works well but

```
df_sample.mode()
```

doesn't work like mean as seen in output below:

Output:[image]

Any ideas why and how can I get mode of all columns using something similar to df.mode()?Btw my purpose is to impute missing data in multiple variables with mode and it didn't replace NaNs with mode in my original data.

```
df_sample['A'].fillna(df_sample['A'].mode())
```

But now I realize, seems like mode itself has a problem in definition. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mode is the most occurring value in a list.  So, in both of your columns, each value appears only once. So the mode for the columns are the all values.

Comment: There is no single mode for your data (right?!).

Comment: @cs95 yes realized that. Thanks!

Comment: but @cs95 this question isn't answered by the question marked as duplicate. The question is related to 'mode' method and not using value counts the traditional way.

Comment: You need to scroll past the accepted answer ;)

Comment: Just learned fillna method works only with suffix 'iloc[0]' unlike mean as mean is unique and mode usually isn't . 'fillna(df.mode().iloc[0])' is the answer for others. Reference here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32619781/7027147. @cs95 I suggest to change the duplicate to this answer instead.