# Replacing empty cells in column with variable value

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I'm trying to replace the emtpy cells of a column called 'City' with the most common value in the same column through the use of the python library (i think) called pandas.

(workin with a csv file here)

This is what i've tried, assume the file is read and ready to be edited:

```
location = df['City'].mode()
basicdf = "df['City'].replace('',"+location+", inplace=True)"
basicdf
```

so the logic here was to use .mode which gives the most frequent value in a row and make that value into the variable 'location'

and then add that variable into the second line of code.
(i dont know how to do all this in the correct way at all.)

the second line of code seemed to be the only way to add whatever variable i desire into this .replace command.

Edit: have tried this code instead, this ends up writing in other columns aswell, other than 'City' which is not great.

```
df['City'].replace('',np.nan,inplace=True)
df = df.fillna(df['City'].value_counts().index[0])
```

any tips would be appreciated, mainly how to achieve what im trying to do ( while not needing to restart from scratch, cause i have a lot of other code in the file using pandas library) and 
how to insert variables into these pandas commands (if even possible).

Comment: does this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32619781/6660373

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Imputation of missing values for categories in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617811/imputation-of-missing-values-for-categories-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, thanks mainly to Pygirl,

```
df['City'].replace('',np.nan,inplace=True)
df['City'].fillna(df['City'].value_counts().index[0], inplace=True)
```

these will first replace the blanks or empty cells with NaNs and then 'fill' in the NaNs with the most common value in the column selected, in this case: 'City'.